# Compare two tables using less than operator in sql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Namely TEAM1 and TEAM2

```
  TEAM 1                     TEAM 2
+--------+-------+      +--------+-------+
| NAME   | VALUE |      | NAME   | VALUE |
+--------+-------+      +--------+-------+
| APPLE  | 5     |      | APPLE  | 4     |
| ORANGE | 8     |      | ORANGE | 12    |
| GRAPES | 10    |      | GRAPES | 12    |
| PEAR   | 12    |      | PEAR   | 9     |
+--------+-------+      +--------+-------+
```

I'm creating a sql query that will return Team2 Name and Value that has lower value(less than) than Team1. Example Result is shown below:

```
Result
+--------+-------+
| NAME   | VALUE |
+--------+-------+
| APPLE  | 4     |
| PEAR   | 9     |
+--------+-------+
```

What sql query should I use? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the result you are looking for.

```
SELECT T2.NAME, T2.VALUE
  FROM TEAM2 as T2 --Base table is Team2
 INNER JOIN TEAM1 as T1 ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME --Join both the tables
 WHERE T2.VALUE < T1.VALUE --Filter condition
```

You can learn more about [SQL Joins from w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
Select b.Name, b.Value
From Team1 as a, team2 as b
Where b.Name = a.Name and
b.Value < a.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t2.* from TEAM1 t1,TEAM2 t2 where t1.NAME = t2.NAME and t2.VALUE < t1.VALUE
```